# why are we going for auto-type storage class?

Tags: c, keyword, automatic-storage

In C, why we go for storage classes? I heard that auto type is the same as the local variable. in that case, why we go for auto type?is there any special by using auto type instead of local variables which is not mentioned as auto.
for example,

```
int a=10;
```

and

```
auto int a=10;
```

both are stored in stack segment and scope of these variables is within the function.so what is the difference between these two? why we go for `auto`-type?

Comment: `auto type instead of local variables`..please read a C book first.

Comment: `auto` is not a type.

Comment: auto type is one of types of storage class. So I mentioned auto-type specifier

Comment: just to complete what Mr. @KerrekSB said, it is a storage-class specifier.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `auto` (keyword) is **not** a type specifier, it's a storage class specifier. Quoting from the standard,

> An object has a storage duration that determines its lifetime. There are four storage
>   durations: static, thread, automatic, and allocated.

To quote `C11`, chapter §6.2.4, *Storage durations of objects*

> An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without the storage-class
>   specifier `static` has automatic storage duration,[..]

and, regarding the *linkage*, (*emphasis mine*)

> The following identifiers have **no linkage**: an identifier declared to be anything other than
>   an object or a function; an identifier declared to be a function parameter; **a block scope
>   identifier for an object declared without the storage-class specifier `extern`.**

So, local variables, satisfying above conditions are by default, having automatic storage duration. You don't have to *explicitly* specify the `auto` keyword.

OTOH, type-specifiers determine the type (of data or variables). Going by the standard definition of type

> The meaning of a value stored in an object or returned by a function is determined by the
>   ***type*** of the expression used to access it.

Comment: where auto keyword is used?

Comment: @Arul do you mean _explicitly_?